# How to get Luaj function parameter names inside java class?

Tags: java, lua, luaj

Is there any way to get the count and names of all the function parameters defined in .lua file?

For eg my test1.lua is

```
function MyAdd( num1, num2, num3)
    local x = 0
    if(num1 <= num2) then
        x = num1 + num2 + num3 
    else
        x = (num1 - num2) + num3     
    end
    return x
end
```

And inside Java class I am trying to execute this function by passing parameter values.

If this Lua function was written by some other user and saved into a folder and the java application loaded this Lua file without knowing what function is inside it. How can I get the name of the function ('MyAdd'), the number of input parameters to this function and also the name of these input Parameters (num1, num2 and num3) inside java

If I know the name of the function and number and order of input parameters I can invoke the function as below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a1 = 5;
    int a2 = 10;
    int a3 = 15;

    Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
    globals.get("dofile").call(LuaValue.valueOf("./luascripts/test1.lua"));

        LuaValue MyAdd = globals.get("MyAdd"); 

        Varargs results = MyAdd.invoke(LuaValue.varargsOf(new LuaValue 
             [] {LuaValue.valueOf(a3), LuaValue.valueOf(a1), LuaValue.valueOf
                 (a2)}));
        System.out.println(results);
}
```

I hope I made myself clear about what am I trying to achieve. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no direct way of doing it, so this was the approach which I took.

Sol specific only to the case mentioned in question.

1) Read the contents of .lua file to a String
 2) Check if the string contains string "function"
 3) Find the index of function-name
 4) Find indices of '(' and ')'
 5) Get parameters between indices from step 4 as a substring.
 6) Split substring when ',' occurs and save to String Array.

```
    String FnctionName = null;
    String[] par_array = null;
    try {
        String contents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./luascripts/test1.lua")));
        if ( contents.contains("function") ) {

            int space = contents.indexOf(" ");
            int left_br = contents.indexOf("(");
            int right_br = contents.indexOf(")");
            FnctionName = contents.substring(space + 1, left_br);
            String params = contents.substring(left_br + 1, right_br);

            par_array = params.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split(",");

            System.out.println(FnctionName);               
            for ( String s : par_array ) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
       }
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```